# Is limit of a sequence equal to the limit of the related function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

### Introduction

By standard definition limits of functions are defined in terms of sequences. Namely, there is a theorem (in my Mathematics class we called it the Heine's theorem),which states:

> Let there be a function $f:D \to \mathbb{R}, \emptyset \ne D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and let $a \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be an accumulation point of $D$. Then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=A\ (A\in \overline{\mathbb{R}} )$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x_n)=A$ for every sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_n=a$ and $x_n \in D\setminus\{a\}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Now here is what I am thinking about. There are certain limits that are really hard to calculate when they are given for sequences, but really easy if we are considering real functions. If we we're asked about a limit of a sequence, we can maybe just think of it as if it was a limit of a function. This would allow us to use L'Hopital's rule, which simplifies calculating of a large number of limits by the great amount.

So when for example considering alternating series( which I am doing currently), we fallback to Leibnitz's alternating series test if the series does not converge absolutely. For example, series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ converges only conditionally. So when applying the AST we see that need to prove find $\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n = 0$. This can be hard in some cases. Wouldn't it we nice if we could use limits of functions, instead of limits of sequences, to prove that those sequences converge. I am not aware that we can. That's what made me think of the theorem above, though I am not sure whether it can be applied in order to prove that such a step would not make the universe explode. So here is my attempt at trying to find an answer:

Let's say we are given the function $f$. We take $x_n = n$, since theorem says that it holds true for any $\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_n = a$. Then, from the theorem above, it seems reasonable that we can write that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}f(n)=\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=A\tag{1},$ thus proving my idea.

### Question

Is my reasoning correct? If not, what am I missing? Would you, if you are a calculus teacher, allow your students to use $(1)$ when working with sequences?

#### Edit

While stating some commonly known limits in the original question I made some mistakes that were kindly pointed out in the comments. Those are now corrected.

Comment: Just a note: You can't use L'Hopital's rule to find $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}$. You *can* use it to find $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$. 

For the limits as $x$ or $n$ approaches $\infty$, you can just use the squeeze theorem, and the only property of the sine function you need is that it's bounded within $[-1,1]$.

Comment: You're right,  L'Hopital's can't be used beause $\lim_{x->\infty}\sin(x) = DNE$. Also the proof i was thinking off was for when $x\to0$, so that's also the mistake on my part. For the proof of that following inequalities are used: $\sin(x) < x < \tan(x)$, $|\sin(x)| < |x|$, and $|\sin(x) - \sin(y)| = | x- y|$

Comment: Ah, sure. So obviously limits as $x\rightarrow 0$ aren't really an issue for sequences, but you could always invert things and be talking about $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin\frac1x}{\frac1x}$

L'Hopital's rule makes this not too hard, and then *because* the continuous limit exists, *then* the limit of the sequence also exists and is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists, then it is equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$; this follows from the definition of limit. However, in general it is *not* true that if the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ exists, then it is equal to $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$; take $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$, for instance.

Comment: Don't both limits diverge?
Edit: I actually meant, is it not that both of those limits do not exist?

Comment: Also the theorem I mentioned has if and only if statement, that is, it's an equivalence relation as far as I know? Wouldn't that imply equality in both ways?

Comment: Actually, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(n\pi)=0$, since  $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\sin(n\pi)=0$. And the theorem that you mentioned assumes that the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists. But $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)$ does *not* exist.

Comment: Ohhhh I see. I was not careful enough. That explains it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: This is a bit off topic. What made me think of this was a series $(-1)^n  tan(\frac{1}{n})$. When finding it's limit for $a_n$ would you say it is "obvious" and that no extra work should be shown? Obviously as n goes to infinity it goes to 0. What could be a more detailed proof? Basically I am unsure which limits I can just handwave and for which ones I have to do some work.

Comment: In this case, $\bigl((-1)^n\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is bounded and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\tan\left(\frac1n\right)=0$. Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\tan\left(\frac1n\right)=0$ too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128440/discussion-between-dumic-branislav-and-jose-carlos-santos).